# Vowel position changer

Tags: code-golf, string, alphabet

## Challenge :

Sort the vowels (only vowels) in the given string .

### Note :

- Vowels are the following characters: A, E, I, O, U
- Vowel sorting is cyclic i.e. After rearrangement the first vowel of sorted string goes where the original first vowel was

---

## Input :

A string line, the original line (consisting of alphabets and white space only all of them in uppercase (save whitespace))

---

## Output :

A sorted string, the given string with vowels sorted (All in uppercase)

## Examples :

### Input == `STACK EXCHANGE`

So the vowels are at index:

```
A -> 1
E -> 2
A -> 3
E -> 4
```

On pushing, indexes become:

```
A -> 1
A -> 2
E -> 3
E -> 4
```

∴ String will be: `STACK AXCHENGE`

---

### Input == `ZOMBIE BRAINZ`

So the vowels are at index:

```
O -> 1
I -> 2
E -> 3
A -> 4
I -> 5
```

On pushing, indexes become:

```
A -> 1
E -> 2
I -> 3
I -> 4
O -> 5
```

∴ String will be: `ZAMBEI BRIONZ`

---

## Note :

You will not change the indexes of constants (non-vowels) and white spaces. Only position of vowels will change.

---

## Restriction :

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes for each language wins

---

Comment: @ovs : You will find all vowels in the sentence re arrange them and then replace them with the new position.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are we supposed to move the vowels (and only the vowels) so that they end up in alphabetical order? Ex. `UAEBOI -> AEIBOU`

Comment: @Scrooble: No , read the note at the end. Only change the position of vowels but do not change the position of constants. I will give an example

Comment: @Scrooble : Yep your example is correct

Comment: @ovs : added an example

Comment: @Scrooble : added another example

Comment: @MuhammadSalman I'd call this "sorting" the vowels, not "pushing" them. I'd also remove the "1 position to the left" bit, if I understand properly.

Comment: @Scrooble : ok canged to sorting , removed that part too

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate... here there is only one valid solution per input because vowels are sorted instead of shuffled.

Comment: @Timtech, most of the solutions to the dupe target will be trivially modified for this challenge - sort lexicographically instead of randomly.